# Rails 4 activemerchant >1.5 for Paypal Pro subscriptions with card options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, activemerchant

Being [activemerchant](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant) such a popular gem, I bet there is more than one solution for the deprecation I found following this [tutorial](https://launchschool.com/blog/paypal-recurring-payments). Ultimate goal is to connect with Paypal for subscriptions using both pp accounts and cards.

Problem begins with GATEWAY call to PaypalGateway at development.rb

```
config.after_initialize do
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
    ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(
       login: "my_login_name.my_company",
       password: "MYPASSWORD",
       signature: "The-Long--Special_signature_from_paypal"
    )
  end
```

Subscriptions controller then triggers the purchase method housed in the model card.

```
def purchase
    response = GATEWAY.recurring(price_in_cents, credit_card, purchase_options)
    create_card_transaction(action: "purchase", amount: price_in_cents, response: response)
    suscription.update_attribute(:purchased_at, Time.now) if response.success?
    response.success?
  end
```

The GATEWAY line triggers an automatic error in latest activemerchant gem. Included at lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal/paypal_recurring_api.rb. This is the error log message:

```
in `purchase': Recurring functionality in ActiveMerchant is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please contact the ActiveMerchant maintainers if you have an interest in taking ownership of a separate gem that continues support for it.
```

I tried to find a branch for paypal subscriptions with no success. Deprecation decision was taken only few months ago.

Anyone else trying branching activemerchant to make it work with Paypal subscriptions? Any example?

I found another gem, [paypal-express](https://github.com/nov/paypal-express), that is specific for Paypal, but does not accepts cards.

Here [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495155/activemerchantresponseerror-while-using-gateway-recurring-method) with no answer. And there is many old tutorials from 2008 to 2011 trying to achieve the recurring communication today deprecated at activemerchant.

Using ruby 2.1.2, rails 4.1.6, activemerchant 1.56.0